# javax.sip.SipException: IO Exception occured while Sending Request

Tags: java, sip, jain-sip

I want to register to the sip server using Jain sip api. However, the error "`javax.sip.SipException: IOException occured while Sending Request`" is returned.

If I can not generate the sip message correctly, network is unreachable: datagram send failed.

It seems correct that the REGISTER SIP message in the code I wrote as logic is output. I just can not be sure of the ports.

The REGISTRANT TICKET produced by the code is as follows.
request: REGISTER sip: test.spoiler.com.tr: 5060 SIP / 2.0
Call-ID: 3235ae8a968869c2525bf1035d05d168@192.168.56.1
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
From: ; tag = 2065198559
To: 
Via: SIP / 2.0 / UDP 192.168.56.1:50600 // I also tried to write the IP address of the Sip server here
Max-Forwards: 70
Expires: 5
Content-Length: 0

```
My sip server that I want to connect to is: test.spoiler.com.tr
AOR address-> sip: test.spoiler.com.tr: 5060
UAS address -> sip: 800@test.spoiler.com.tr: 5060
```

I also pointed to the UAS address as the user of the Sip I want to register at the same time. So;
toHeader-> 
fromHeader-> ; tag = 2065198559
 
I wrote my sip server address so that Via connects to the first sip server. In normal cases it gets the IP on the local host.
Although I tried Local Host IP, the result does not change.

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.*;
import javax.sip.*;
import javax.sip.address.*;
import javax.sip.header.*;
import javax.sip.message.*; 
public class exampleListener implements SipListener {

SipFactory sipFactory;
SipStack sipStack;
ListeningPoint listeningPoint;
SipProvider sipProvider;
HeaderFactory headerFactory;
AddressFactory addressFactory;
MessageFactory messageFactory;
int tag = (new Random()).nextInt();
long LCseqDegeri = 1;
exampleGUI GUI;

public exampleListener(exampleGUI gui) {
    try {
        this.GUI = gui;

        sipFactory = SipFactory.getInstance();
        sipFactory.setPathName("gov.nist");

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("javax.sip.STACK_NAME", "sipStack");
        sipStack = sipFactory.createSipStack(properties);

        String sIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        int iPort = GUI.getPort();
        String protocol = "udp";
        listeningPoint = sipStack.createListeningPoint(sIP, iPort, protocol);

        sipProvider = sipStack.createSipProvider(listeningPoint);
        sipProvider.addSipListener(this);
        headerFactory = sipFactory.createHeaderFactory();
        addressFactory = sipFactory.createAddressFactory();
        messageFactory = sipFactory.createMessageFactory();

        GUI.setBATDAU("SIP Başlatıldı: " + sIP + ":" + iPort);

    } catch (UnknownHostException | TooManyListenersException | InvalidArgumentException | ObjectInUseException | PeerUnavailableException | TransportNotSupportedException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

public void sendMessage() throws UnknownHostException {
    try {

        Address desAddress = addressFactory.createAddress(GUI.getUAS());
        System.out.println("UAS destination Address: " + desAddress);
        Address AORAddress = addressFactory.createAddress(GUI.getAOR());
        System.out.println("AOR Address: " + AORAddress);
        ToHeader toHeader = headerFactory.createToHeader(desAddress, null);
        System.out.println("toHeader: " + toHeader);
        FromHeader fromHeader = headerFactory.createFromHeader(desAddress, String.valueOf(tag));
        System.out.println("fromHeader: " + fromHeader);
        String sIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();//GUI.getSipServer();
        System.out.println("Via ilk sip sunucusuna bağlanır. SIP Sunucusu: " + sIP);
        ViaHeader viaHeader = headerFactory.createViaHeader(sIP, GUI.getPort(), "udp", null);
        ArrayList viaHeaders = new ArrayList();
        viaHeaders.add(viaHeader);
        System.out.println("viaHeader:" + viaHeader);
        MaxForwardsHeader maxForwardsHeader = headerFactory.createMaxForwardsHeader(70);
        System.out.println("maxForwardsHeader: " + maxForwardsHeader);
        CallIdHeader callIdHeader = sipProvider.getNewCallId();
        System.out.println("callIdHeader: " + callIdHeader);
        CSeqHeader cSeqHeader;
        cSeqHeader = headerFactory.createCSeqHeader(LCseqDegeri, Request.REGISTER);
        System.out.println("cSeqHeader: " + cSeqHeader);
        ExpiresHeader expiresHeader = headerFactory.createExpiresHeader(5);
        URI requestURI = AORAddress.getURI();
        Request request = messageFactory.createRequest(requestURI, "REGISTER",
                callIdHeader, cSeqHeader, fromHeader, toHeader, viaHeaders, maxForwardsHeader);
        request.addHeader(expiresHeader); 
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("request: " + request);

        sipProvider.sendRequest(request);


        GUI.displayMessage("Talep : " + request.toString());
    } catch (ParseException | InvalidArgumentException | SipException ex) {
        for (StackTraceElement ste : ex.getStackTrace()) {
            System.out.println(ste);
        }
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

> Detailed description of the error

```
gov.nist.javax.sip.SipProviderImpl.sendRequest(SipProviderImpl.java:741)
exampleBasic.exampleListener.sendMessage(exampleListener.java:90)
exampleBasic.exampleGUI.cmdGOIActionPerformed(exampleGUI.java:199)
exampleBasic.exampleGUI.access$200(exampleGUI.java:16)
exampleBasic.exampleGUI$3.actionPerformed(exampleGUI.java:115)
javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2238)
java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2296)
java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4897)
java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4475)
java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2282)
java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
javax.sip.SipException: IO Exception occured while Sending Request
```

My libraries:
- javax.sip -> jain-sip-api  1.2.1
- javax.sip -> jain-sip-ri  1.2.244 
- org.mobicents.slee.media -> media-rtp  1.0
- javax.media jmf  2.1.1e 
- org.zenframework.z8.dependencies.commons log4j-1.2.17  2.0

How do I get the IO error. How can I resolve it? When I looked through the internet, I did not find the solution of this error.

Comment: What's the output of this line: System.out.println("request: " + request);

Comment: The output is as follows: request: REGISTER sip:test.spoiler.com.tr:5060 SIP/2.0
Call-ID: 7a5cbb7d35eae3e6fc90eb74225d25f8@192.168.56.1
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
From: <sip:800@test.spoiler.com.tr:5060>;tag=-1634219715
To: <sip:800@test.spoiler.com.tr:5060>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.56.1:50600
Max-Forwards: 70
Expires: 5
Content-Length: 0

Comment: Most likely reasons are the DNS lookup of test.spoiler.com.tr fails or the IP behind test.spoiler.com.tr is not routable from the selected interface. I suggest you replace the request URI to use the IP directly to test for DNS issues, and then check the routing table on your computer if the target is routable.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it does not direct from the selected interface?

Knowing the domain information there, I entered differently. However, when I enter it with domainle and ip, the result does not change. I'm getting the same error.

I'm sure the sip server that I'm trying to connect to works. Because a system written in a different writing language actively works without problems.

When I tried Java language, I could not find where I made the mistake. When I examined the library, I could not find out what caused this mistake.

Comment: It's best to enable debug logs and attach them here. See how to do it here https://github.com/usnistgov/jsip/blob/master/src/examples/android/simplecallsetup/Shootist.java#L221

Comment: I installed Log4J and added debug and logged as you said.
I think IOException occurs because of a "java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: Datagram send failed" error at the root of the error.


13221 [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR gov.nist.javax.sip.SipProviderImpl - Error
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: Datagram send failed

The datagram error is not due to the fact that the sip message is not produced correctly.

Comment: Netowrk unreachable is typically caused by routing problem. Check your routing table. InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(); is not a good way to bind your sockets. Most machines have multiple interfaces and if you pick one that is not properly routed to the outside network you get this error. Use something like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/listing.html to enumerate local interfaces and select one that routes to outside instead.

Comment: The other thing you can check is if your interface has dual support for ipv4 and ipv6, then check if the DNS resolves to ipv4 or ipv6 address, as not to mix them up. For debugging i suggest disable ipv6 entirely.

Comment: @VladimirRalev Thank you for the answer. I could access the sip server when I gave the correct ip. But this time I got 401 authorization error.  ProsessResponse also has CientTransaction as null

In another question, you gave the following example as an answer. So I went, but I could not fix it.

According to the example https://github.com/deruelle/jain-sip/blob/master/src/test/unit/gov/nist/javax/sip/stack/reinvitechallenge/Shootist.java, I did not even authorize.